# Cannot invoke 'XCTAssertEqual' with an argument list ((ErrorType), XMPPError)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rx-swift

In MyModule, I have this enum:

```
enum MyError: ErrorType {
    case failToSendMessage
    case notAuthenticated
    case noResponseReceived
}
```

In MyModuleTests:

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyModule

class MyModuleTests: XCTestCase {
    func testNotAuthenticated() {
        myClass.doSomething()
        .subscribeError { error in 
            XCTAssertEqual(error, MyError.notAuthenticated)
        }
    }
}
```

`doSomething` returns an `Observable`.

Why do I get this error message:
`Cannot invoke 'XCTAssertEqual' with an argument list ((ErrorType), MyError)` ?

Comment: what type of object is returned by  subscribeError ?? i mean the "error" object?

Comment: (Edited the question)
The error object's type is an `MyError`, which is an `ErrorType` too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add an extension conforming Equatable for your MyError.

```
extension MyError: Equatable
{
    static func == (lhs: MyError, rhs: MyError) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.failToSendMessage, .failToSendMessage):
            return true;

        case (.notAuthenticated, .notAuthenticated):
            return true;

        case (.noResponseReceived, .noResponseReceived):
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And then, it's pretty simple to Assert your error.

```
if let error = result.error {
                    XCTAssertTrue(error == MyError.notAuthenticated,"API returns 403");
                } else {
                    XCTFail("Response was not an error");
                }
```

I.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests , here you are trying to compare `(ErrorType)` with `MyError` using `XCTAssertEqual`

1.Check why you are getting error as `(ErrorType)` instead of `ErrorType`

2.Try comparing after converting(Type cast) `ErrorType` to `MyError` error.

Comment: 1. I can't find how I got `(ErrorType)` instead of `ErrorType`


2. Type casting causes the error changed into `Cannot invoke 'XCTAssertEqual' with an argument list ((ErrorType), ErrorType)`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, ErrorType can't be compared directly:

```
XCTAssertEqual(error, MyError.notAuthenticated as ErrorType)
// Cannot invoke 'XCTAssertEqual' with an argument list ((ErrorType), ErrorType)

XCTAssert(error == (MyError.notAuthenticated as ErrorType))
// Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'ErrorType' operands
```

To accomplish the same thing, I did this:

```
        switch error {
        case MyError.notAuthenticated:
            ()
        default:
            XCTFail()
        }
```